# Attach Cloud Service Worker instance to Network Security Group

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

Giving a bit of context: I'm using Cloud Service (Classic) along with a Virtual Machine (Classic)

the VM:

- is assigned a network security group "NSG1"
- running a process to which cloud service workers should connect to via TCP (I can connect to it from another VM in same network security group)

the Cloud Service workers:

- upon starting (they are started from a script on the VM) should connect to the process running on the VM

My issue is that right now I haven't found a way to assign the cloud workers to the network security group "NSG1", is it possible and how can it be done?

If possible I'll be looking for the correct API calls to do this, but even a solution which involves using the portal would help me figure out what steps need to be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can associate a NSG to a cloud service in two ways:

1. Directly to the cloudservice by expressing it in the .cscfg file
2. Associating the NSG to the subnet where the cloud service is deployed.

Thanks.